# ERROR TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.toggle is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I am testing a simple recursive Treeview component in **angular4** using the below code. But whenever I try to expand the children view on `toggle()`.

I am getting an exception error:

> ERROR TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.toggle is not a function

Thanks

**tree-view.component.ts**

```
export class TreeViewComponent implements OnInit {  
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {}     
  @Input() directories: Directory[];
}
```

**tree-view.component.html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let dir of directories">
    <label (click)="dir.toggle()"> {{ dir.title }}</label>
    <div *ngIf="dir.expanded">
      <tree-view [locations]="dir.children"></tree-view>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Directory.ts

```
 export class Directory{

      title: string;
      children: Directory[]
      expanded = true;
      checked = false;

  constructor() {

  }

  toggle() {
    this.expanded = !this.expanded;
  }

  getIcon() {
    if (this.expanded) {
      return '-';
    }
    return '+';
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you create `Directory` instance?

Comment: I do api call and deserialize it directly to directories:Directory[] which is passed to the treeview component

Comment: Serialization doesn't create class instance. You have only array of objects

Comment: Hmm interesting any suggestion how to solve that?

Answer (score 10):

Like yurzui suggested, in case you are just **typing** your data, you don't have class instances, so the method `toggle` isn't available. If you truly want to have your array with instances of your `Directory` class, add the properties to constructor and when you get the data from api, create instances of your objects, so shortened version:

```
export class Directory {
  title: string;
  expanded: boolean;

  constructor(title: string, expanded: boolean) {
    this.title = title;
    this.expanded = expanded 
  }
}
```

and in your api call:

```
return this.httpClient.get<Directory[]>('url')
  .map(res => res.map(x => new Directory(x.title, x.expanded)))
```

Now you have access to the `toggle` method.

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ghpznv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: This seems not working with recursive array. I have tried to include children property as well but the issues still exists

Comment: could you show the attempt you have made now, which causes you trouble.

Comment: Hi, l literally implementing the code you provided. I have no errors with the mapping but the above mentioned exception still persist when i click on the toggle function.

Comment: what's about that `children:Directory[]` property in your class? Does not seem correct to me?

Comment: I had also error in my class, but that is fixed now, and I added a demo, so it should work. But still wondering about that `Directory` array inside your `Directory` class :) If it's an array of some class, you'd need to create instances of that class too.

Comment: I am trying to create a treeview with n-depth. This is why i do include a children:Directory[] in the main object. In the sample you created i think its only relevant to 2 level depth? By the way i do appreciate that you are still with me trying to solve it:)